# How to force to pass a required url path via get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route

```
    collection do
      get :show_logs
    end
```

And I want the user should request `show_logs/[:id]`.

Forbid user to send `show_logs` request without required `id`

What's the better ways to get it ?

### UPDATE

If now, I wrote my rule as following,

And trying to access without `:id`, `http://localhost:3000/tool/mvaas/relay_queries/show_logs`

I'll get the error  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in xxx`

### routes

```
  get '/tool/mvaas/relay_queries/show_logs/:id', to: 'tool/mvaas/relay_queries#show_logs', :via => :get, :as => 'show_logs_tool_mvaas_relay_queries'

  namespace :tool do
    namespace :mvaas do
      resources :relay_queries do
        collection do
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: is your question still open?

Answer (score 2):

You should put it into `member` instead of `collection`

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :show_logs
  end
end
```

It will be accessible with the url `/users/:id/show_logs`

If you absolutely want the url to be `/users/show_logs/:id` then you should go with

```
get '/users/show_logs/:id', to: 'users#show_logs'
```

before your `resources :users do` block

Comment: Hi, if i follow your tips, I still get some problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if params exist by following way:

```
if(params.has_key?(:one))
```

If exist- request will done.
If absent - redirect/render or show notice.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
get "show_logs/:id" => "controller#action"
```

with updates: just write something like:

```
  namespace :tool do
    namespace :mvaas do
      resources :relay_queries do
        collection do
          get "show_logs/:id", action: "show_logs"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```